# JavaScript : show the measure of data transfer between client and server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, c#-4.0

If you saw in Mozilla fire fox browser, when you clicked on submit button; in bottom of page wrote something like (javascript:__doPostBack(.....) or waiting for www.yahooforexample.com) and after waiting alert wrote reading data from www.yahooforexample.com or in another browsers loader image or show something else. I have a question about these:
Can i show the measure of data transfer between client and server?

It means when fire fox has a java script post back or transfer data between client and setting i want show progress bar or something else to show user the measure of data transferring.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in java script when a page load in iframe we can say how many data is loaded now.
i see the example here .
visit http://project.mahemoff.com/jquery-iframe/